# UK Passport with French Dates

Tags: uk, passports

I have noticed that my passport has a french date for August ie - août.
I understand that there are French words on a UK Passport but do any of you actually have the diacritic above the u (û) on your passport date of birth?

Comment: http://www.cairngormmountain.org/wp-content/uploads/formidable/Keri-UK-passport-1024x749.jpg

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here. You state that your passport has a circumflex above the U as in AOÛT. Are you asking whether other UK passport holders who are also born in August also have the circumflex? Why do you think they wouldn't? Clearly @Berwyn has provided another example of this circumflex on a UK passport.

Comment: Interesting. [Berwyn's example](http://www.cairngormmountain.org/wp-content/uploads/formidable/Keri-UK-passport-1024x749.jpg) has one, with the issuing agency shown as FCO ([this FCO](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/foreign-commonwealth-office), I guess). [pnuts' example](http://thewhistleblowers.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/ChristiansborgPassportCarl-Vernon.jpg) lacks one, with the issuing agency shown as [UKPA](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/hm-passport-office). Maybe it depends on which computer system is used...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a survey. (From the "[What types of questions should I avoid asking](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" page in the help centre, this comes under the following categories of off-topic questions: "Every answer is equally valid", "Your answer is provided with the question and you expect more answers" and "No actual problem to be solved".)

Comment: Remark: when writing in all-caps, accents are optional in French, so technically both versions are correct.

Answer (score 4):

The [ICAO specifications for passports](http://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p3_cons_en.pdf) state that passports in English, French or Spanish should also include one of the other two languages for certain data fields. [The UK has chosen to use French](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/comment/letters/7941477/Why-French-is-still-essential-to-a-British-passport.html). (By contrast, US passports use English and Spanish.)

> Captions in French in the British passport (Letters, August 11) are explained by the International Civil Aviation Organisation standard, which most countries adhere to in order to ensure that their passports are accepted worldwide.
>
> The standard recommends that, where the language of the issuing state is English, French or Spanish, the issuing state should use one of the other two languages.
>
> The second language for ours has long been French. Until 1772, both Latin and English were used for passports, then French alone until 1858, only after which passports were written in English.
>
> Kevin Sheehan
>
> Director, Identity and Passport Service
>
> London SW1

Thus, your passport data page will include both English and French text.

Comment: My passport (in English) doesn't have any French translations, so not sure how much this rule is enforced.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: If the issuing country's language is not English/French/Spanish, it's enough to translate/transliterate into one of those languages. And they are "should"s, not "must"s.

Comment: My US passport has some preprinted information in English, French and Spanish, other in English only. Spanish is a relatively recent addition, the first few having been in English and French. But none of them shows any of the bearer-specific data, including dates, in any language other than English.

Comment: Correction: my passport from 1988 has dates in French and English, as in the British examples. I don't have my 1974 passport handy. The 1988 one is also the last without Spanish; maybe when they added the 3rd language they decided to stop putting multilingual months because it would be too cluttered.